# sed over multiple lines to replace a single number

Tags: sed

Im new to sed and found some instructiones to that kind of probmen, but none of them worked for me.

I have a file called var.tf with that entry:

```
variable "nb_instances" {
  description = "Specify the number of vm instances"
  default     = "3"
}
```

and want to replace the "3" with "4".

I tried to create that bash skript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sed 's/variable \"nb_instances\" {
  description = \"Specify the number of vm instances\"
  default     = \"3\"
}/variable \"nb_instances\" {
  description = \"Specify the number of vm instances\"
  default     = \"4\"
}/g' var.tf
```

but it doesn´t work and gives an error:

sed: 1: "s/variable \"nb_instanc ...": unterminated substitute pattern

Can anyone help me with that? I also tried to include \n for the new lines.

Comment: It would not work even if you used `\n` in the pattern: `sed` operates on individual lines by default.

Comment: if you only have one line in the input file containing `default`, you can use `sed '/default/ s/"3"/"4"/' var.tf` if this is not okay, let us know why

Comment: thanks for your answers, there are multiple identical lines with "default" and "3" must be a wildcard, it is unclear what number there will be.

Comment: so, is there a simpler qualifier? like `variable "nb_instances"` is distinct? and if so, is it guaranteed that `default` will be second line after that? `sed -E '/variable "nb_instances"/ {n;n; s/"[0-9]+"/"4"/}'` would work for such a scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^variable "nb_instances" {/{:a;n;s/"3"/"4"/;Ta}' file
```

Focus on the first line beginning `variable "nb_instances" {` then continue reading/printing lines until the string `"3"` is replaced by `"4"`.